# Idiomatic Proof by Contradiction in Isabelle?

Tags: proof, isabelle, isar

So far I wrote proofs by contradiction in the following style in Isabelle (using a pattern by [Jeremy Siek](http://ecee.colorado.edu/~siek/ecen3703/spring10/quick-ref2.pdf)):

```
lemma "<expression>"
proof -
  {
    assume "¬ <expression>"
    then have False sorry
  }
  then show ?thesis by blast
qed
```

Is there a way that works without the nested raw proof block `{ ... }`?

Answer (score 9):

There is the rule `ccontr` for classical proofs by contradiction:

```
have "<expression>"
proof (rule ccontr)
  assume "¬ <expression>"
  then show False sorry
qed
```

It may sometimes help to use `by contradiction` to prove the last step.

There is also the rule `classical` (which looks less intuitive):

```
have "<expression>"
proof (rule classical)
  assume "¬ <expression>"
  then show "<expression>" sorry
qed
```

For further examples using `classical`, see [$ISABELLE_HOME/src/HOL/Isar_Examples/Drinker.thy](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/website-Isabelle2020/dist/library/HOL/HOL-Proofs-ex/Drinker.html)

Comment: If `<expression>` is huge, it is convenient to start with `assume "~ ?thesis"`.

Comment: An aside: `ccontr` (which AFAIK abbreviates "classical contradiction") is also classical reasoning. Thus it sounds a bit strange to call the second pattern _classical reasoning_.

Comment: @chris, you are right, I should change this reference to "classical reasoning".  But then what would we the best word to describe the rule "classical"?

Comment: The rule "classical" expresses classical reasoning in its full brutality, without any auxiliary connectives.  In the form "ccontr" it looks a bit more civilized, but it is equivalent.  The names for these rules in Isabelle/FOL and HOL go back to Larry Paulson, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 4):

For better understanding of rule `classical` it can be printed in structured Isar style like this:

```
print_statement classical
```

Output:

```
theorem classical:
  obtains "¬ thesis"
```

Thus the pure evil to intuitionists appears a bit more intuitive: in order to prove some arbitrary thesis, we may assume that its negation holds.

The corresponding canonical proof pattern is this:

```
notepad
begin
  have A
  proof (rule classical)
    assume "¬ ?thesis"
    then show ?thesis sorry
  qed
end
```

Here `?thesis` is the concrete thesis of the above claim of `A`, which may be an arbitrarily complex statement.  This quasi abstraction via the abbreviation `?thesis` is typical for idiomatic Isar, to emphasize the structure of reasoning.